# Get wearable device rotation in degrees from 0-360 around X axis

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am using the `Rotation Vector` sensor to try to track how many degrees rotation 0-360 around the `X` axis (aka wrist movement) the user moves.

I am using the `SensorManagers` getOrientation to the the yaw, pitch and roll this way

```
float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, sensorData.getValues());

float[] orientation = new float[3];
SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientation);
```

with the watch face pointing up it gives 0 degrees like I want but when I rotate I only get +/- 90 degree increments. rotating left gives me +90 degrees and rotating right gives me -90 degrees. I i continue rotating lets say from the +90 degrees I start getting negative degrees so when the watch is face down (180 degrees) is shows `0` again. using 90 degree increments is going to make it difficult to accurately get the actual rotation angle.

Is there a way to go from +/- 90 degree increments to 0-360 degrees?

Comment: Can you just use the `z` rotation to find whether the device is face up or down (it's a matter of whether z is positive or negative I believe)...From there, your +/- 90 should be convertible into 360.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `z` rotation value to find out whether the watch is face up or down.  This determines the perspective you are viewing from and gives you 4 quadrants, instead of the 2 that you started with.

If `z` is positive: watch is face up.  If `z` is negative, it is face down.

From here, you can create a coordinate system for conversion.

If the watch is facing up, coordinate is `90+x_rotation`. Since rotating right gives [-90,0), and rotating left yields [0,90], this gives degrees of `[-90+90,90+90] = [0, 180]` Which is what we would expect of a watch facing up on the wrist.

If the watch is facing down, coordinate is `270+x_rotation`.  Quadrant 3 gives negative values of 90, making the values range from `[270+-90,270] = [180,270]`.  Likewise, Quadrant 4 has positive values of 90, creating a range of `[270,90+270]`. So a watch facing down gives `[180, 360]`.

Combined, we get the complete `[0,360]` device rotation range.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is probably going to get me on the right track but the `z` value goes from `0` to `-1` where `0` is face down. I am still not sure how I know what direction it has been rotated (left or right)